# How can I create another KT1 accounts under my TZ1 account?

Tags: tezos-client, ledger, account, address

I want to delegate to various bakers using just one ledger, but I'm not sure how to create a new KT1 account via command line after the Babylon upgrade.

Comment: I don't use command line, but happy to answer how to do this via TezBox (which I use with a Ledger).